# Can True Polymorph transform an object (a tree) into the Champion (CR 9) from Volo's?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph

I'm running a high-level Norse-themed adventure with Odin and Thor running around messing up giants.

The Odin-wizard used [*true polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) to create a human from an oak log (see the saga), and he wanted it to be the CR9 [Champion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/champion) from *Volo's Guide to Monsters* (p. 212).

I let him do it because it was cool. I have in my head, however, that the rules only allow an average example of the race - like a human commoner, not a champion, but I can't find the rule or ruling that makes me think that.

Is creating a CR9 human champion a RAW/RAI use of *true polymorph*?

Comment: I never thought of that one. I will use this on my players... As an alternative to the dragon's teeth scene from Jason and the Argonauts... 
"Behold the teeth of Odin..."

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The *[true polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph)* spell says:

> You can turn an object into any kind of creature, as long as the creature’s size is no larger than the object’s size and the creature’s challenge rating is 9 or lower. The creature is friendly to you and your companions. It acts on each of your turns. You decide what action it takes and how it moves. The DM has its statistics and resolves its actions and movement.

Looks to me it says CR 9 or lower, and so creating a CR 9 human Champion (Volo's Guide to Monsters, p. 212) is perfectly legit.

Let the messing up of giants begin.

Comment: You might add that shapechange states "You transform into an average example of that creature, one without any class levels or the Spell casting trait." As an example of when you have to pick the average type.

Comment: In the spirit of "spells don't do anything that's not in their description", it's useful to know what the spell would have said if the restriction was in place.

Comment: You might add the spell states "If the spell becomes permanent, you no longer control the creature", so the Champion isn't necessary loyal to the wizard.

Comment: @ravery OK, removing my comments.

Comment: @enkryptor though in this case - a human Champion created from a log by Odin, and led in battle against giants - continuing loyalty is at least reasonably likely.

Comment: Until not long ago, the Champion was a tree which was ever in danger of becoming an improvised giant greatclub. I don't think loyalty will be tricky.

Comment: I enjoyed all of your comments. Shapechange spell was the wording that I got stuck in my head. Thanks @ravery